# Possible to put component in array and render them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a component and put that component in an array to render it later. I don't want to take the data from the component, pass it, then reconstruct it. Is this possible?

What I am trying to do is currently not working and gives the error:

> The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions

I don't know if that is referring to this part of the code.

Code to create `TodoItem` component and add it to array:

```js
addTodo() {
   if (!this.isTodoItemSet()) {
        this.throwError("You must input a todo!");
        return;
   }

   this.clearError();
      const todoItem = this.createTodoItem();
      this.addItem(todoItem);
   },

   createTodoItem() {
      const todoItem = <TodoItem id="this.newItemId" title="this.todoItem" />;
      this.newItemId += 1;
      return todoItem;
   },

   addItem(todoItem) {
      this.$props.todoItems.push(todoItem);
      console.log(this.$props.todoItems);
   },
...
```

Attempting to render the components from the array

```html
<template lang="">
  <div>
    <li v-for="item in this.$props.todoItems" :key="item.id">
      <component v-bind:is="item"></component>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    TodoItem,
  },

  props: {
    todoItems: [],
  },
};
</script>
<style lang=""></style>
```

Comment: in some components the `data` option should be `data(){return {}}`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Is there more specific information regarding the necessity to make it empty object?

Comment: Is there a reason to use `<component>` when you know you’re going to render `<TodoItem>` anyway? This special tag is only used when you want to dynamically load different named components. Also, VueJS doesn’t allow you to do what React does, according to your code for the function `createTodoItem`, unless you have a special JSX plugin installed. Finally, you shouldn’t be mutating props in a component.

Comment: @EstusFlask I want to say that data option should look like `data(){return {....}}`

Comment: @Terry there wasn't a reason, I was just testing to see if it caused any issues and forgot to change it back

Comment: Also, adding ``data(){return {}}`` didn't do anything

Comment: Adding `data` is not relevant to the question. The issue is with how you're confusing JSX template with Vue template in your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the `createTodo` function to this

```
createTodoItem() {
      const todoItem = Vue.extend(TodoItem);
      const todoItemInstance = new todoItem();
      todoItemInstance.id = this.newItemId;
      todoItemInstance.title = this.todoItem;
      this.newItemId += 1;
      return todoItemInstance;
    },
```